# Identify the Length of the Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Tags: java, strings, programming-challenge

## [Length of Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/description/)

### Problem ([from Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/description/))

> Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

### Examples

Given `abcabcbb`, the answer is `abc`, which the length is `3`.

`bbbbb`, the answer is `b`, with the length of `1`.

Given `pwwkew`, the answer is `wke`, with the length of `3`. Note that the answer must be a substring, `pwke` is a subsequence and not a substring.

### Discussion

#### Approach

1. Keep track of the substring characters in a `Set`.
2. Keep track of the evaluated ("seen") characters in a `Queue`.
3. Iterate through the characters in the input `String`.

   - If the substring characters include the current character

     1. Iterate through the head of the seen characters `Queue` until you find a match in the `Queue`.
     2. For each non-matching character from the `Queue`, remove it from the `Queue` and remove it from the `Set`.
     3. Once you find a matching character, remove it from the head of the `Queue` and add it to the tail of the `Queue`.
   - Else

     1. Add the current character to the `Set`
     2. Add the current character to the tail of the `Queue`.
   - If the `size` of the `Set` is greater than the current longest substring length, replace the current longest substring length with the `Set` `size`.

#### General Questions

- Naming sucks - open to a better name - there's gotta be something better than `LongestSubstringWithoutRepeatingCharactersLengthIdentifier`...right?
- Is there a cleaner implementation that uses other data structures?

### Implementation

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class LongestSubstringWithoutRepeatingCharactersLengthIdentifier {
    public static int identify(String s) {
        int longestSubstringLength = 0;
        Set<Character> substringCharacters = new HashSet<>();
        Queue<Character> seenCharacters = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        for (char currentCharacter : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (substringCharacters.contains(currentCharacter)) {
                while (seenCharacters.peek() != currentCharacter) {
                    substringCharacters.remove(seenCharacters.poll());
                }
                seenCharacters.poll();
            } else {
                substringCharacters.add(currentCharacter);
            }

            seenCharacters.add(currentCharacter);

            if (substringCharacters.size() > longestSubstringLength) {
                longestSubstringLength = substringCharacters.size();
            }
        }
        return longestSubstringLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked about naming.  Perhaps use `max...` instead of `longest...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advice 1**

```
Queue<Character> seenCharacters = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
```

[`java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) is a concurrent data structure; I suggest you use [`java.util.ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/ArrayDeque.html). Also, I think the better name would be `characterWindow`.

**Opinion 1**

```
Set<Character> substringCharacters = new HashSet<>();
```

I would rename the above to `substringCharacterFilter`.

**Opinion 2**

```
if (substringCharacters.size() > longestSubstringLength) {
    longestSubstringLength = substringCharacters.size();
}
```

I think the above would be more readable like this:

```
if (longestSubstringLength < substringCharacterFilter.size()) {
    longestSubstringLength = substringCharacterFilter.size();
}
```

**Alternative implementation**

```
public static int identify(String s) {
    int longestSubstringLength = 0;
    Set<Character> substringCharacterFilter = new HashSet<>();
    Deque<Character> characterWindow = new ArrayDeque<>();

    for (char currentCharacter : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (substringCharacterFilter.contains(currentCharacter)) {
            while (characterWindow.getFirst() != currentCharacter) {
                substringCharacterFilter.remove(characterWindow.removeFirst());
            }

            characterWindow.removeFirst();
        } else {
            substringCharacterFilter.add(currentCharacter);
        }

        characterWindow.addLast(currentCharacter);

        if (longestSubstringLength < substringCharacterFilter.size()) {
            longestSubstringLength = substringCharacterFilter.size();
        }
    }

    return longestSubstringLength;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `LinkedBlockingQueue` is not the best choice. It's based on a linked list, which lacks spacial locality. An continuous array-backed queue would be more efficient (there're a few options in the standard library).
2. ```
    if (substringCharacters.size() > longestSubstringLength) {
        longestSubstringLength = substringCharacters.size();
    }
   ```

   I'd use the `Math.max` method here.
3. You can avoid using the queue altogether. You can keep the leftmost index of the current "window" and the set instead.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         Queue<Character> seenCharacters = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
> ```

Why the concurrent version?  If you really want this, just use the regular version.

```
        Queue<Character> seenCharacters = new LinkedList<>();
```

It's not like the method is reentrant.  There's no state for threading to confuse.

I'm ignoring the question of whether `LinkedList` or `ArrayDeque` is better here.  Because ...

The truth is that you don't need it.  You're just duplicating the string.  Instead, iterate over the string by index.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char currentCharacter = s.charAt(i);
```

Also change the `Set` to a `Map` (or even an array).

> ```
>         Set<Character> substringCharacters = new HashSet<>();
> ```

becomes

```
        Map<Character, Integer> lastSeen = new HashMap<>();
```

and add

```
        int lastDuplicate = 0;
```

Leading to

```
        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }

        int longestSubstringLength = 1;
        int lastDuplicateIndex = -1;
        Map<Character, Integer> lastSeen = new HashMap<>();

        lastSeen.put(s.charAt(0), 0);

        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char current = s.charAt(i);

            Integer lastIndex = lastSeen.get(current);
            if (lastIndex != null && lastDuplicateIndex < lastIndex) {
                lastDuplicateIndex = lastIndex;
            }

            lastSeen.put(current, i);

            if (longestSubstringLength < i - lastDuplicateIndex) {
                longestSubstringLength = i - lastDuplicateIndex;
            }
        }
```

I used a less Hungarian scheme for naming.  I.e. no types in the names.

This uses the map to track where the current character was seen last.  If that's after the last duplicate, point the last duplicate index to the place where the current character was seen last.  That's the new last duplicate.

I tested this on `pwwkew` (3), `abcabcab` (3), and `bbbbb` (1).

Comment: hmmm...I'm not sure this would work for `aaa` (which should return `1` but I think this method would return `3` due to the `longestSubstringLength = i - lastDuplicateIndex` for the first `a`).

Comment: It works for `bbbbb` (returns 1).  Note that it updates `lastDuplicateIndex` for each `a`.  I did make a copying error that I've fixed now.